# How to get certain files from TFS using PowerShell?

Tags: tfs, branch, powershell-2.0

After we branch for release, there are certain configuration files that need to be updated. Currently, I'm getting latest version of all the source code on the specific (new) branch. This is time consuming and takes up a lot of disk space.

Is there a way to search/loop through the particular branch and only getting files that match a certain criteria?

E.g:

```
Loop through files under branch on the TFS server
If file name matches "foo.proj" or file name matches "foo.ini" 
Get latest version of the file
```

The "get" part is easy using the command line interface to TF (`tf get $/project/foo.proj`). I'm not to sure how to loop through the server objects without getting latest version first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in the end:

Custom install the TFS Powershell snap in using the tftp.exe that you download.

Add the snap in:

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}
```

Powershell script:

```
param( [string] $ServerBranchLocation )

$tfs=Get-TfsServer -name http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs
$TfExePath = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"

$matchFoo = "foofile.foo"

foreach ($item in Get-TfsChildItem $ServerBranchLocation -r -server $tfs) 
{ 
    if ($item -match $matchFoo)
    { & "$TFExePath" get $item.ServerItem /force /noprompt }
}
```

I couldn't find a way to get the latest version using the snap in, so I had to use the ol' trusty tf.exe.

Comment: To get the latest version use `Update-TfsWorkspace` without listing a version (perhaps with `-Force` to always get whatever the server thinks you have in your workspace). You can pass the same version specifications that `tf get` uses ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be.aspx)) with `-version`. Eg. `Update-TfsWorkspace ‹file› -force -version 'T'` to get the latest.

Comment: What about x86 vs x64 ? http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2009/12/29/program-files-environment-variable-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the TFS PowerShell Snapin from the TFS PowerToys (you need a custom install to select).

After loading the snapin in a 32bit PSH instance (`Add-PSSnapin  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`) you can use:

- `Get-TFSItemProperty` on a folder to get a list of items under source control.
- `Update-TfsWorkspace` to get or update all or specific files/folders into your workspace.

***Update***: You can install the PSH TFS snapin for 64bit yourself having installed it for 32bit via the PowerToys (see comments) in which case this is not limited to a 32bit PSH instance.

Comment: I was under the impression that the TFS PowerShell Snapin is installed by default when installing TFS PowerToys. Doing a custom install gave me the snap in. Also, using the 32bit PSH worked.

Comment: It is loaded into a TFS specific Powershell console, but not original the Windows Powershell console.  You can certainly update your profile (found with $profile) to load the TFS snapin.

Comment: I had to follow the one step in this [link](http://nzbart.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/getting-tfs-power-tools-2010-working-on.html) to get the snap in to work in my 64-bit console. I also updated my profile to load the snap in so that I don't have to do it in every script (and it's also portable for other user's to use).

Comment: @Alicia Nice link, I think it is better to allow the snapin to install itself (in case of other dependencies). From elevated 64bit PSH: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll'`

Comment: Thanks @Richard! I moved over to a new Win8 machine and this helped a lot.